# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, multithreading

i have a problem whenever i Refresh the prograss bar i get the error The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it 
how can i remove it
shashank

```
     backgroundWorker12 = new BackgroundWorker();
     timer1.Enabled = true;
      //cancel any async processes running for the background worker
     //backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
     backgroundWorker12.DoWork += (s, args) =>
     {

         BackgroundWorker worker2 = s as BackgroundWorker;
         worker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

         float percentageDone = 20f;
         //check if the user status and update the password in xml
         CheckUseridPwd();


         //call the function to sync the wall chart data

         //call the function to sync event relate data

         percentageDone = 100f;
         ValidateLogin2(txtUserID.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Password.Trim(), -1); 
         worker2.ReportProgress((int)percentageDone);

     };`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit looks like it's using UI controls from the wrong thread:

```
 ValidateLogin2(txtUserID.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Password.Trim(), -1);
```

I suggest you capture the user and password in local string variables above the code which adds the event handler - you can use those captured variables within your delegate. That way everything should be on the right thread:

```
backgroundWorker12 = new BackgroundWorker();
timer1.Enabled = true;

string user = txtUserID.Text.Trim();
string password = txtPassword.Password.Trim();
backgroundWorker12.DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
    // ... same code as before up to here
    ValidateLogin2(user, password, -1); 
    worker2.ReportProgress((int)percentageDone);
};
```

Comment: its work great but when we bind the data with combobox as above in code it will give same error

Comment: @SHASHANK: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Bind which data? As above in which code - mine or yours? Which thread are you trying to perform the binding in?

Comment: there is easier way Dispatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: @Rev: It depends on what you want to do. For reporting simple progress, `BackgroundWorker` is pretty handy. For other things I would generally use a Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use the [RunWorkerCompleted event of the BackgroundWorker,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx) since you're accessing the UI only after progress is 100% i.e. done.. 
Then you wouldn't have to worry about thread-affinity of WPF UI controls - since the event handler is invoked again on the right/ UI Thread.

The other option (if you need to access the UI controls before the work is complete) is to cache the object
 returned by Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher on the UI Thread before the work starts and then use object.Invoke to marshal to the right thread from the thread pool thread that is executing your DoWork handler. See [some code here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking `ValidateLogin2`

you can either do it directly from your code shown, or in `ValidateLogin2` check if the method itself requires invoking. If not, go ahead and validate, but if it does, then have it invoke itself

```
void ValidateLogin2(...)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)    
  {        
    //Invokes itself if required        
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate(){ValidateLogin2(...);}));
  } 
  else 
  {
     //validate login here    
  }
}
```